# Can we script something in groovy to hit ALM’s API

Tags: alm

I am using ALM and I need something to be scripted in groovy so that I can hit ALM's API. Can anyone help or provide some link or material where I can find solution. I have heard about Scriptom, will it work?

Comment: I use ALM API to send out generate status report. Please check here for more details. http://www.testautomationguru.com/hp-alm-qc-automated-status-report-email/

Comment: Thanks :) But I have found dragonfly does the same thing, and we do not need to code anything.its simple..!!

Comment: Great. Can you give me the link plz?

Comment: I use this to integrate SoapUI with ALM. where SoapUI is a testing tool. http://www.agiletestware.com/dragonfly.html